# asking user for input valid command in java

Tags: java

I am developing my own shell(command prompt).   [When
a user enters a built-in command, the shell is required to search   and execute the respective code accordingly.]

I have created my code using command split, and command parameters in order to store my commands. but one thing I'm confused about is that making a command that is not in the list.
I think of using if statement to print invalid comment (for example)

```
if (command!="exit")||(command!="about")||(command!="date")||(command!="time")||(command!="hist")||(command!="notepad")
                    ||(command!="")||(command!="hist -h")||(command!="hist -l")||(command!="c"){

System.out.println("invalid command");
}
```

but this statement is way too much if there are tons of command line.. so is there an easy way of implementing it !?

Answer (score 1):

If this java and all commands are Strings and input `command` is also a String you can simplify what you are trying to do by creating a list of valid commands and do a contains check.

```
List<String> validCommands = Arrays.asList("exit", "about", "date");
if (!validCommands.contains(command)) {
    System.out.println("invalid command");
}
```

That being said there are better ways to maintain a list of valid command outside java program such as properties file and load list of valid commands from that file. This will make your program more maintainable.

Comment: What if command includes integer for example.. like if i want to  print previous x number of used commands, ill be using (hist  x)    as X indicates integer number of used commands.. and hist = history of commands

Comment: `hist x` will still be a string, string combined with integer can be cast to a string

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Map<String, Command>`, to keep track of the available commands.  If the command is not in the map then it's invalid. For example:

```
public class Shell {
    private final Map<String, Command> supportedCommands;

    public Shell(Map<String, Command> supportedCommands) {
        this.supportedCommands = supportedCommands;
    }

    public void execute(String command, String[] args) {
        Command c = supportedCommands.get(command);
        if (c == null) {
            System.out.println("invalid command");
        } else {
            c.execute(args);
        }
    }


    public interface Command {
        public void execute(String[] args);
    }

}
```

Comment: same issue as above solution (((((What if command includes integer for example.. like if i want to print previous x number of used commands, ill be using (hist x) as X indicates integer number of used commands.. and hist = history of commands )))))